# "Int" Object is not Subscriptable python

Tags: python, pygame, integer, typeerror

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but as far as I've checked, none of them have the answer I'm looking for.

I have this bit of code:

```py
if grasses.angles[grasses.angle_num] < grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num]:
    grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num] -= 1
elif grasses.angle[grasses.angle_num] > grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num]:
    grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num] += 1
```

The problem is that on the `if` and `elif` statements it keeps coming out with the error`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

I'm not quite sure what that means but I think it has something to do with calling a integer from a list.

Comment: The error message means that either `grasses.angles` or `grasses.angles2` is not  a list, but an int.

Comment: no they're both lists

Comment: I've rechecked and it's still a list...

Comment: Is `grasses.angle` an `int` ?

Comment: no it's a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. `grasses.angle` must to be `grasses.angles`:

<s>`elif grasses.angle[grasses.angle_num] > grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num]:`</s>

```py
elif grasses.angles[grasses.angle_num] > grasses.angles2[grasses.angle_num]:
```

Comment: yeah that worked. Should've checked that before asking

Comment: @DuckDuck This question is a candidate for to be deleted.

Comment: I can't delete it